# Dependent preferences display wrong color font when disabled

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-theme, android-styles

In my app I am using several preferences, including some of them related with dependencies using the following attribute: `android:dependency="pref_key"`.

Basically, when the checkbox is not selected, all the other preferences below are disabled:

[image: Preferences without style definition]

The problem happens when I setup back the following 3 lines in my custom theme:

```
<style name="AppThemeOrange" parent="@style/AppTheme">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/OrangeMain</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/OrangeDark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/OrangeLight</item>
(...)
```

The colors defined on these 3 attributes also override the default font color of the disabled preferences:

[image: Preferences with style definition]

The preferences are still well disabled, but the fonts displayed make believe the contrary...

I searched in the default Holo Light styles and theme, but I have no idea where this is defined and why the styles above override these ones.

Did anyone already meet the problem?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you should define a color state list and put it inside the /res/color folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#FF00ff00"/>
    <item android:color="#FFff0000"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am trying it but it seems `state_disabled` is not an option available.

Comment: Yes I figured it out just after, I did a quick test and it worked, thanks for the quick help!

Comment: android:state_enable should be android:state_enabled

Comment: @Blackbelt Do I just need to put this piece of code in my color file? How will preferences know what to look for?

Comment: no, not in the color file. you have to create a folder called color inside res and put the piece of code in a xml file. Then you can use with the textColor attribute of the textview @user2474562

Comment: @Blackbelt, but `ListPreferences` and `EditTextPreferences` don't have an option for textcolor. I'm having the exact same question the OP did.

Comment: @user2474562, I am not familiar with ListPreferences and EditTextPreferences, but probably you can use the a theme as the op does

Comment: @Blackbelt, I want to. But how do I define the color for disabled state in theme? I've created a different theme for the settings activity, but I'm not sure how to define the color for disabled state within the theme.

Comment: @user2474562 you have to create a folder called color inside res and put the piece of code in a xml file. And then in the theme use @color/name_of_xml. E.g `<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/name_of_xml</item>`

Comment: Make sure "android:textColor" is not defined, or this doesn't work.