# Android: change color of disabled text using Theme/Style?

Tags: android, colors, styles, textview, themes

I have the following colors defined in my color.xml:

```
<color name="gold">#d49e43</color>
<color name="gold_disabled">#80d49e43</color>
```

And the following theme:

```
<style name="Theme.Example" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">       
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/gold</item>
</style>
```

In my SettingsActivity, I have a CheckBoxPreference and a Preference that depends on it.  When The CheckBoxPreference is unchecked, the Preference is disabled, however, because of the custom gold text color that I set, it doesn't get "greyed out" like it does with the default color.  How do I change this in XML?  I've tried setting:

```
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryDisableOnly">@color/gold_disabled</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverseDisableOnly">@color/gold_disabled</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryNoDisable">@color/gold_disabled</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryNoDisable">@color/gold_disabled</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverseNoDisable">@color/gold_disabled</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverseNoDisable">@color/gold_disabled</item>
```

but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out more or less by accident, but if you subclass Preference and override the onBindView(), you can achieve the "grayed out" effect when a preference is disabled:

```
@Override
protected void onBindView(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBindView(view);
    TextView title = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    TextView summary = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.summary);

    if (title.isEnabled()) {
        title.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.gold));
    }
    else {
        title.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.gold_disabled));
    }

    if (summary.isEnabled()) {
        summary.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
    }
    else {
        summary.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.orange_disabled));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 41):

I know I'm late. However, I had exactly same problem and I fixed just now.

I found a way to fix it using resource files only. I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17123161/4860513

Basically, you can create a color selector under: res/color/

**Note:** You must create folder color if it does not exist.

For me, I did it:

**res\color\primary_text_color_selector.xml (For Title)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#80000000"/>
    <item android:color="#FF000000"/>
</selector>
```

**res\color\secondary_text_color_selector.xml (For Summary)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#80000000"/>
    <item android:color="#C0000000"/>
</selector>
```

Then, In my preference style, I did:

**res\values\styles.xml**

```
<!-- Preference Screen Theme --> 
<style name="AppTheme_PreferenceScreenStyle">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text_color_selector</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text_color_selector</item>
</style>
```

**in SettingsFragmentActivity.java**

```
public class SettingsFragmentActivity extends PreferenceFragment {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
        PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen = getPreferenceScreen();

        mContext = preferenceScreen.getContext();
        mContext.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_PreferenceScreenStyle);

        ...
    }
}
```

This way, Title and Summary are grayed out when option is disabled.

I'm just sharing this solution since I have same problem and it may help someone

Comment: Excellent solution with all the needed step to implement it - helped me a lot

Comment: Would this work for changing the color of checkbox or radio button icons? If so, what would the item names in the styles.xml file be?

Comment: Make sure "android:textColor" is not defined, or this doesn't work.

Comment: I found that `android:textColorPrimary` didn't work for the title, however `android:textColor` did (in styles.xml)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at how Google did it for their themes, you would notice this for light (Platform.AppCompat.Light ) :

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/abc_primary_text_material_light</item>
<item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
```

And this for dark theme (Platform.AppCompat) :

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
<item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/abc_primary_text_material_light</item>
```

And the colors of those are set as such:

**abc_primary_text_material_dark.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/primary_text_disabled_material_dark"/>
    <item android:color="@color/primary_text_default_material_dark"/>
</selector>
```

**abc_primary_text_material_light.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/primary_text_disabled_material_dark"/>
    <item android:color="@color/primary_text_default_material_dark"/>
</selector>
```

So, you should do the same (create the files and the references to them in the themes file), to handle light&dark theme, and to handle the states of the text color.

To use it in the app, you can use `?android:textColorPrimary` or `?android:textColorPrimaryInverse` .

Same goes for secondary text color and tertiary, BTW.