# setShouldDisableView is not working.

Tags: android, android-layout

Created a preference file for settings in android. When I uncheck a CheckBoxPreference I want its dependent preferences to turn out to grey color (i.e to potray). I had tried using, setShouldDisableView() but its not working. Suggest me the idea to greyout the dependent Checkboxpreference's (title and checkbox), but in default only the color of checkbox is changing.

Answer (score 2):

Create separate `xml` file in `drawable` folder and paste the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

            <item android:drawable="#D3D3D3" android:state_checked="true"/>
            <item android:drawable="#ffffff" android:state_checked="false"/>

        </selector>
```

This `xml` file name set as `android:background="@drawable/filename"` in your check box tag xml. Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

In your theme use selectors for primary/secondary colors instead of using "pure" colors. See also: [Android: change color of disabled text using Theme/Style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769198/android-change-color-of-disabled-text-using-theme-style)